# How to add timestamps to mongoose schema subfields?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to add `createdAt` and `updatedAt` timestamps in subfields of `otp` in `generate: {}` and `verify:{}`

I know that using `{ timestamps: true }` will add the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` timestamps to the whole schema.`

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({    
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    name: { type: String }, 
    mobileNumber: {
        isVerified: {type: Boolean, default: false},
        otp: {
            generate: {
              attempts: {type: Number, default: 0},
              total: {type: Number, default: 0},
              createdAt: {type: Date},
              updatedAt: {type: Date}
            },
            verify: {
              attempts: {type: Number, default: 0},
              total: {type: Number, default: 0},
              createdAt: {type: Date},
              updatedAt: {type: Date}
            }
          }
    }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

What is correct solution to add individual timestamps to subfields? Is it correct to do the same by adding `{timestamps: true}` to the subfields?

```
            generate: {
              attempts: {type: Number, default: 0},
              total: {type: Number, default: 0},
              {timestamps: true}
            },
            verify: {
              attempts: {type: Number, default: 0},
              total: {type: Number, default: 0},
              {timestamps: true}
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have do define a separate schema for your subfields, then use that as the type of your subfields.

```
const otpSchema = new mongoose.Schema({    
    attempts: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    total: { type: Number, default: 0 }
}, {
    _id: false, // omit _id fields for subfields
    timestamps: true // timestamps options for subfields
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({    
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    name: { type: String }, 
    mobileNumber: {
        isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        otp: {
            generate: otpSchema, // use the defined schema
            verify: otpSchema
        }
    }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Comment: How Can I change timestamps createdAt and updatedAt format is like (DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss)

Answer (score 3):

*Okay, it seems like this answer became more popular, so a will extended it with full coverage.*

#### What does `{timesamps: true}` do and how it does what it does?

The original `{timesamps: true}` code, from mongoose.js can be found [here @ line:1150](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schema.js)

How exactly `timestamps: true}` knows when and how it should update `updatedAt` field, and don't update `createdAt` ?

By this code:

```
  this.pre('save', function(next) {
    
    /**
    * SKIP CODE A BIT
    */

    if (!skipUpdatedAt && updatedAt && (this.isNew || this.isModified())) {
      let ts = defaultTimestamp;
      if (this.isNew) {
        if (createdAt != null) {
          ts = this.$__getValue(createdAt);
        } else if (auto_id) {
          ts = this._id.getTimestamp();
        }
      }
      this.set(updatedAt, ts);
    }

    next();
  });
```

So each time [when mongoose driver triggers `.save` on MongooseDocument](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html), this code got executed (if timestamps set to `true`, of course)

There is a big difference between MongooseDocument (object) and js-Object/JSON/result of `find({}).lean()`

You could cast various methods on MongooseDocument, like [`.isNew`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isNew) (this is exactly how mongoose understood that `updatedAt` field should be updated, and `createdAt` should not). or convert it `.toObject()` or `.toJSON()` Full list of methods can be [found here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html).

Just to be sure: when you are using `.find` without `.lean()` option, you are dealing with MongooseDocument(s), but if enable it, you will receive plain JavaScript objects.

#### How to create you own implementation of `{timestamps: true}` for your own schema?

It's easy to achieve the same results, via `default` values and with using `setters` in your schema:

```
  createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now, set: v => v.Date.now()}
```

You could read [more about setters here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/getters-setters.html#setters).

Also, it could be any function you want, for example you could modify value each time on any insert || modify operation (and `update`, too)

> ..*Or you could avoid setters and update `updatedAt` field manually in code, every time, via: `model.findAndUpdate({your_field: value}, {your_field: value, updatedAt: Date.now())` each time.*

So, in the end, using setters (or manual query update), will gave you the same result as `timestamps: true` option, but you could apply it to every sub-document in your schema.

Comment: Hi, how to update the timestamps via `$set` ? Should i do this?  `userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.updatedAt = Date.now();
    return next();
});`

Comment: @TamashiKaizen I updated my original answer to avoid misunderstanding. You could update field `updatedAt` with your update query, or use `setters` to achieve the same result. but without modifying you own queries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such feature fall in the scope of the database capabilities to provide, nor mongoose to enable.

You may want to create two other entities - `Attribute` and `AttributeValue` with **OneToMany** relationship, to track values changes timestamp.

Well, that's how we tackled the issue on my main current project.

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same problem and mine was a pretty straightforward solution.

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({ email: String }, { timestamps: true });
```

my result with createdAt and updatedAt automatically added:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("60ba2cb3bca3572f6ca1b525"),
   "title" : "First post with timestamp",
   "content" : "Test post timestamp",
   "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-06-04T13:37:55.025Z"),
   "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-06-04T13:37:55.025Z"),
   "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: OP question is specific for subfields: does it work in that case?